# Numpy lomax mean function return "inf" instead of value

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Following [this tutorial](https://catchjs.com/Blog/Churn), I have created the following `churn.py` file:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats as stats

#duration of alive subscriptions
censored = np.array([419,513, ... ,316,14])
#duration of completed subscriptions
uncensored = np.array([389,123,340, ... ,56,31])

#Log likelihoods for censored data
def log_likelihood_lomax(args):
    shape, scale = args
    val = stats.lomax.logpdf(uncensored, shape, loc=0, scale=scale).sum() + stats.lomax.logsf(censored, shape, loc=0, scale=scale).sum()
    return -val

res_lomax = sp.optimize.minimize(log_likelihood_lomax,   [1, 1], bounds=((0.001, 1000000), (0.001, 1000000)))

print("lomax shape", res_lomax.x[0], ", scale=", res_lomax.x[1])
print("lomax mean", stats.lomax.mean(res_lomax.x[0], scale=res_lomax.x[1]))
print("lomax median", stats.lomax.median(res_lomax.x[0], scale=res_lomax.x[1]))
```

***Note***: the `...` in the `censored` & `uncensored` arrays are here for confidentiality purposes. In the actual script, I have included real values instead.

When I run this script with `python3 churn.py`, I get the following results:

```
lomax shape 0.36948878639375643 , scale= 1440.4384891101636
lomax mean inf
lomax median 7961.447172364986
```

I know for a fact that the value returned for the median is incorrect.

But most importantly, I don't understand why the lomar mean returns `inf`.

Is there anything wrong in my script?

Comment: A little bit difficult to say what is going on without values. Debug your cost function, seems like you have a call to 0 or 1 in your logpdf or logsf.

Comment: Instead of using `...` for data that you want to hide, it would be better if you put in some fake data, and showed the unexpected results using that fake data.  Then we can run the script and reproduce the results.  How about something like `censored = np.array([419, 513, 20, 30, 40, 316,14])` and `uncensored = np.array([389, 123, 340, 20, 30, 40, 56, 31])`?

Comment: *"I know for a fact that the value returned for the median is incorrect."* How do you know this?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I know this because we are calculating a duration in days, with values all comprised between a couple of months and three years, so the mean cannot be higher than 10 years. The problem is that I used a Lomax distribution while I should have used a Weibull distribution.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks for suggesting that. I figured the problem is not related to the code but to the distribution law I used.

Comment: Yes, using Weibull instead of Lomax will make a big difference. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result shows

```
lomax shape 0.36948878639375643
```

That is, using scipy's notation, the shape parameter `c` is 0.36948878639375643 (in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomax_distribution), `c` is α).
For `c` ≤ 1, the mean of the distribution *is* infinite (that is, the integral that defines the mean diverges).

You asked *"Is there anything wrong in my script?"*  There is one important change that I recommend: after you call `minimize`, check that `res_lomax.success` is True before you use the values in `res_lomax.x`.  Something like this:

```
res_lomax = sp.optimize.minimize(log_likelihood_lomax, [1, 1], bounds=((0.001, 1000000), (0.001, 1000000)))
if res_lomax.success:
    print("lomax shape", res_lomax.x[0], ", scale=", res_lomax.x[1])
    print("lomax mean", stats.lomax.mean(res_lomax.x[0], scale=res_lomax.x[1]))
    print("lomax median", stats.lomax.median(res_lomax.x[0], scale=res_lomax.x[1]))
else:
    print("minimization failed:", res_lomax.message)
```